# Flutter get display size setting

Tags: android, flutter, pixel

i need to detect current display size setting. How can i detect it?
[image]

Comment: can you try double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

Comment: That "Display size" setting varies between devices, but most likely it sets the dpi. Probably [`MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/devicePixelRatio.html) is the closest thing

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dhafin Rayhan said, device pixel ration , was solution

Answer (score -1):

To detect the current display size setting in Flutter, you can use the MediaQuery class with the current context of your widget. Here’s an example of how to get the width and height of the screen:

```
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```